# chrome e mysql não abrem após mudar permissão na pasta /opt

Tags: linux, ubuntu

peço ajuda para solucionar o seguinte problema.

estava usando o **XAMPP** para rodar aplicações PHP, e precisei editar o arquivo **php.ini** que fica em **/opt/lampp/etc/**

```
OBS: dentro da pasta opt/ tem outras 2 pastas google/ e lampp/
```

ao salvar o arquivo **php.ini** surgiu erro de permissão, então abri o Terminal me loguei como ROOT

```
# sudo su
```

fui ate a pasta raiz e entrei com o seguinte comando:

```
# chown -R meu_usuario /opt
```

( depois vi que teria sido melhor **chown -R meu_usuario /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini**, mas a caca já estava feita )

após isso consegui salvar o **php.ini**, porém... após reiniciar a máquina.
o navegador **Google chrome** e o banco de dados **MYSQL** do **XAMPP** não funcionam mais :'(

já voltei a permissão da pasta opt/ para o root

```
# chown -R root /opt
```

mas ainda sim, não funciona o chrome nem o banco de dados MYSQL.

Meu sistema

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

agradeço desde já pela força

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As permissão padrão é essa:

`drwxr-xr-x  11 root     root     4096 Mar 18 19:17 opt`

Veja se sua pasta ta assim também, se não tiver rode o comando `sudo chmod -R 755 /opt`

Depois tente reinstalar os pacotes usando `apt-get install --reinstall <pacote>` ou removendo e instalando de novo;

Comment: grato pela atenção, como verifico a permissão padrão da pasta **opt/** ?

Comment: use o comando `ls -al /` ele vai listar todas as pastas no diretório `/` aí só observer

Comment: Cara me ajuda, dei o comando `sudo chmod -R 644 /opt` e agora não consigo entra na pasta **opt/** meu trabalho ta dentro da pasta **opt/lampp/** não posso perder!

Comment: faz assim loga como sudo `sudo su` no terminal e depois digita `nautilus`, ele vai abrir tipo o explorer o windows, aí vc pega seus trabalhos faz um backup delesno pen-drive ou outro lugar que queira

Comment: me adicione no hangout gwmoura@gmail.com

Comment: Ok, vou criar uma conta lá e já te add, vlw